# Possible career paths

Tags: soft-question

I currently hold a Bachelors in Computer Science and a Minor in Physics.  As far as that goes, I've taken courses in the basic things (University Physics 1 and 2), Thermodynamics, Circuitry and Modern Optics.  I also read about various topics online in my spare time.  I'm also planning on going for a Masters in Computer Engineering at NYU Poly.

My question is what are some possible Physics related career paths for someone with my background?  I just graduated this passed May, so I'm fresh out of the academic world.  Are there places in National Labs for people like myself?  I live probably no more than an hour or so from the Brookhaven National Lab on Long Island and would like to somehow get involved there.  Is such a thing even feasible?

Comment: Given that you're just asking for yourself, this is too specific of a question to be generally useful.

Comment: Yea, fair enough, got a good answer anyway :)

Comment: OK cool. Also, part of the reason for closing this is that we don't really want to encourage questions about careers and other things that aren't really physics - a few of them are okay, but not too many. For future questions like this, [chat] is a good place to bring them up. (I know it's pretty dead most of the time, but you can just post a message there and people will see it and respond to it later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - there are places.  Most large accelerator complexes like Brookhaven, SLAC, ORNL, etc, have groups dedicated to development of software for accelerator controls and/or data analysis.  You can find the relevant job descriptions at the different lab websites and see where you might be a good fit.